# How to extract exact union type from object key strings in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got an object like this

```
const MY_OBJECT = {
  'key': 'key val',
  'anotherKey': 'anotherKey val',
};
```

Is there a way to extract from this object `'key' | 'anotherKey'` type ?

Comment: Are you looking for Object.keys(MY_OBJECT) ?

Comment: I think the question is more about typescript types .. at least in my reading.. then again everything looks like a nail when you are a hammer :P

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To get a type that is a union keys of a variable you need to use `keyof typeof variableName`.

```
const MY_OBJECT = {
    'key': 'key val',
    'anotherKey': 'anotherKey val',
};
type MY_OBJECT_KEYS = keyof typeof MY_OBJECT // "key" | "anotherKey"
```