# How to extract exact union type from typed object key strings in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I've got an object like this

```
interface MY_OBJECT_INTERFACE {
  [key: string]: string
}
const MY_OBJECT: MY_OBJECT_INTERFACE = {
  'key': 'key val',
  'anotherKey': 'anotherKey val',
};
```

Is there a way to extract from this object 'key' | 'anotherKey' type ?

"keyof typeof MY_OBJECT" didn't works.

related question: [How to extract exact union type from object key strings in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126004/how-to-extract-exact-union-type-from-object-key-strings-in-typescript)

Comment: Please see the answer to the linked question; if I translate the code from there to here I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJqv6m).

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your comment!! Your answers got me what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

As `MY_OBJECT_INTERFACE` allows any string as key, it's not possible to extract the type of the keys. If the keys are always known you could just change `MY_OBJECT_INTERFACE` to somthing like @LihnNguyen suggested and then the you can go with the related issue, but I guess that's not what you're looking for.

If the object is dynamic (which I assume it is), the only thing you could do is use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of the keys and then work with that. This is of course no type and only a string array, but at least to my knowledge it's the best typescript can do for you.

Answer (score -1):

You try this way

```
interface MY_OBJECT_INTERFACE {
  key: string,
  anotherKey: string
}
const MY_OBJECT<MY_OBJECT_INTERFACE> = {
  'key': 'key val',
  'anotherKey': 'anotherKey val',
};
```